# Retrieve data from sqlite database to android layout

Tags: android

I am creating an edit text profile consists of 3 activities:MainActivity,EditTextPage and ProfilePage.In the MainActivity ,when i login using an id,I have to get the entire user details in the profile page.User data is stored in the database.But when i am login, am getting error like this.
Help me to solve this.

```
10-12 12:10:29.935 9419-9419/? E/libprocessgroup: failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10089: Read-only file system
10-12 12:10:29.935 9419-9419/? W/Zygote: createProcessGroup failed, kernel missing CONFIG_CGROUP_CPUACCT?
10-12 12:10:29.935 9419-9419/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
10-12 12:10:30.074 9419-9419/com.example.aparna.login I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
10-12 12:10:30.107 9419-9419/com.example.aparna.login W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
10-12 12:10:30.134 9419-9419/com.example.aparna.login I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>
    Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>
10-12 12:10:30.174 9419-9436/com.example.aparna.login D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
10-12 12:10:30.175 9419-9419/com.example.aparna.login D/Atlas: Validating map...
10-12 12:10:30.209 9419-9436/com.example.aparna.login I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
10-12 12:10:30.210 9419-9436/com.example.aparna.login W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
10-12 12:10:30.227 9419-9436/com.example.aparna.login D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xa3c0f280: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
10-12 12:10:30.239 9419-9436/com.example.aparna.login D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa3c0f280: ver 2 0
10-12 12:10:30.244 9419-9436/com.example.aparna.login D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
10-12 12:10:30.274 9419-9436/com.example.aparna.login D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa3c0f280: ver 2 0
10-12 12:10:30.402 9419-9419/com.example.aparna.login W/art: Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.DropDownListView.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
10-12 12:10:33.900 9419-9419/com.example.aparna.login E/string: ==rtretrt
10-12 12:10:33.900 9419-9419/com.example.aparna.login D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
10-12 12:10:33.901 9419-9419/com.example.aparna.login E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.aparna.login, PID: 9419
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.aparna.login.ProfilePage.setDataToPage(ProfilePage.java:48)
        at com.example.aparna.login.DbCreate.getData(DbCreate.java:92)
        at com.example.aparna.login.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:62)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
10-12 12:10:36.485 9419-9419/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 9419 SIG: 9
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.aparna.login;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public TextView tv_enterid;
    public EditText edittext_id;
    public Button btn_login,btn_newuser;
    public String id;
    public Boolean result;
    public DbCreate db;
    public ProfilePage profilePage;
    public Cursor cs;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        db=new DbCreate(this);

        profilePage=new ProfilePage();
        tv_enterid=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_firstname);
        edittext_id=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext_id);
        btn_login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        btn_newuser=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_newuser);

        btn_newuser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),EditTextPage.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


        btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                id=edittext_id.getText().toString();
                if(id.isEmpty()){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"fill the name filed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                else if(!id.matches("\\d+")){
                    edittext_id.setError("ENTER ONLY NUMERALS");
                }

                else{
                    result=db.searchData(id);
                    if(result) {
                        db.getData(id);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"you are successfully logged in",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfilePage.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }

                    else
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "plz register", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });


    }
}
```

DbCreate.class

```
package com.example.aparna.login;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static android.os.Build.ID;

public class DbCreate extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME="SAMPLE_DB";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION =1;
    public static final String TABLE_NAME="SAMPLE";
    public static final String USER_ID="ID";
    public static final String USER_FIRSTNAME="FIRSTNAME";
    public static final String USER_LASTNAME="LASTNAME";
    public static final String USER_GENDER="GENDER";
    public static final String USER_DOB="DATEOFBIRTH";
    public static final String USER_ADDRESS="ADDRESS";
    public  ProfilePage pp=new ProfilePage();




    public DbCreate(Context context){

        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);


    }

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+"("+USER_ID+" TEXT,"+USER_FIRSTNAME+" TEXT,"+USER_LASTNAME+" TEXT,"+USER_GENDER+" TEXT, "+USER_DOB+" TEXT ,"+USER_ADDRESS+" TEXT)");
        Log.e("table","created" );
    }

    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db,int oldversion,int newversion){
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
        Log.e("data entered","on upgrade method" );
    }

    public int duplicateData(String id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        String query="SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+ USER_ID+" =?";
        Cursor cs=db.rawQuery(query,new String[]{id});
        return cs.getCount();

    }

    public void insertUser(String id,String firstname,String lastname,String gender,String dob,String address ) {
        Log.e("data","here is"+id+firstname +lastname+gender+dob);

        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();


                contentValues.put(USER_ID, id);
                contentValues.put(USER_FIRSTNAME, firstname);
                contentValues.put(USER_LASTNAME, lastname);
                contentValues.put(USER_GENDER, gender);
                contentValues.put(USER_DOB, dob);
                contentValues.put(USER_ADDRESS, address);
                db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
                Log.e("data inserted", "in database");

    }


    public int userCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        int count = cursor.getCount();
        cursor.close();
        return count;
    }


    public void getData(String id){
       // pp=new ProfilePage();
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        String query="SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+ USER_ID+" =?";
        Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(query,new String[]{id});
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            String f = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("FIRSTNAME"));
            Log.e("string","=="+f );
            pp.setDataToPage(f);
        }

        else
            cursor.close();
    }


    public  boolean searchData(String id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        String query="SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+ USER_ID+" =?";
        Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(query,new String[]{id});

        if(cursor.getCount() <= 0){
            cursor.close();
            return false;
        }
        else {
            cursor.close();
            return true;
        }
    }



    public void deleteAll(){

        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
        db.execSQL(" DELETE   FROM "+ TABLE_NAME);
        Log.e("all records", "are deleted" );
    }
}
```

ProfilePage.java

```
package com.example.aparna.login;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ProfilePage extends AppCompatActivity {
    public TextView tv_id,tv_firstname,tv_lastname,tv_gender,tv_dob,tv_address,tv_title,firstname,lastname,gender,dob,address,id;
    public ImageView img_profile;
    public Button btn_edit;
    public Cursor cs;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_page);


        tv_id=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_id);
        tv_firstname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_firstname);
        tv_lastname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_lastname);
        tv_gender=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_gender);
        tv_dob=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_dob);
        tv_address=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_address);
        tv_title=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
        id=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.id);

        firstname=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.firstname);
        lastname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.lastname);
        gender=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.gender);
        dob=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.dob);
        address=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.address);

        img_profile=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_profile);

        btn_edit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_edit);

        }


    public void setDataToPage(String name){

        firstname.setText(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: `ProfilePage` is your activity. You can't initialize it by `profilePage=new ProfilePage();` It calls only by `Intent`. So just remove that line.

Comment: check your TextView id in your profile page XML. Maybe you should use  `tv_firstname.setText(name)`;

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the getData() method is retrieving data?

```
 public String getData(String id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        String query="SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME+" WHERE ID = " + id;
        Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(query,new String[]{id});
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            String f = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("FIRSTNAME"));
            Log.e("string","=="+f );
            return f;
        }

        else{
            cursor.close();
        }
      return f;
    }
```

Then in your MainActivity add `intent.putExtra("FIRSTNAME",temp);` to the string `temp`

```
btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             ...
                else{
                    result=db.searchData(id);
                    if(result) {
                        String temp = db.getData(id);

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"you are successfully logged in",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfilePage.class);
                        intent.putExtra("FIRSTNAME",temp);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }

                    else
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "plz register", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
```

And then in ProfilePage

In the constructor put  `getIncomingIntent();`

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_page);


        tv_id=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_id);
        tv_firstname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_firstname);
        tv_lastname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_lastname);
        tv_gender=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_gender);
        tv_dob=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_dob);
        tv_address=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_address);
        tv_title=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
        id=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.id);

        firstname=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.firstname);
        lastname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.lastname);
        gender=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.gender);
        dob=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.dob);
        address=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.address);

        img_profile=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img_profile);

        btn_edit=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_edit);
         getIncomingIntent();

        }
```

And then add the following method:

```
public void getIncomingIntent(){
        if(getIntent().hasExtra("FIRSTNAME")){
          String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("FIRSTNAME");
             firstname.setText(name);
        }
    }
```

I didn't test it so you might need to do some adjustments but I hope this gives you an idea.

Answer (score 0):

Error lies here...

```
firstname=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.firstname);
```

The id firstname you are initilizing for textview does not belong to activity_profile_page.
Check whats the id in activity_profile_page.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are facing because you are assigning null value in textField.
So to fix the issue you need to change your code a little bit like.

you should create a model

```
ProfileData.Java

public class ProfileData {
public String firstName = null;
public String lastName = null;
public String id = null;}
```

Now you have to make some change in getData method define in **DbCreate.java**

```
 public ProfileData getData(String id){
    ProfileData pp=new ProfileData();
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    String query="SELECT * FROM "+TABLE_NAME+" WHERE "+ USER_ID+" =?";
    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery(query,new String[]{id});
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        pp.firstName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("FIRSTNAME"));
        pp.lastName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("LASTNAME"));
        pp.id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ID"));
    }

    else
        cursor.close();
    return pp;
}
```

Now make some change to get the data from Db and pass it to next activity

```
btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            id=edittext_id.getText().toString();
            if(id.isEmpty()){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"fill the name filed",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            else if(!id.matches("\\d+")){
                edittext_id.setError("ENTER ONLY NUMERALS");
            }

            else{
                result=db.searchData(id);
                if(result) {
                    ProfileData profileData = db.getData(id);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"you are successfully logged in",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfilePage.class);
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putString("firstName",profileData.firstName);
                    bundle.putString("lastName",profileData.lastName);
                    bundle.putString("id",profileData.id);
                    intent.putExtras(bundle);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

                else
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "plz register", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
```

In the above code you can see I get the data from **DbCreate.java** and sending the data using Intent to ProfilePage activity.

To read the value in in **ProfilePage.java** add some code like

```
public class ProfilePage extends AppCompatActivity {
public TextView tv_id,tv_firstname,tv_lastname,tv_gender,tv_dob,tv_address,tv_title,firstname,lastname,gender,dob,address,id;
public ImageView img_profile;
public Button btn_edit;
public Cursor cs;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_page);



    firstname=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_firstname);
    lastname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_lastname);
    setDataToPage();

}


public void setDataToPage(){

    firstname.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("firstName"));
    lastname.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("lastName"));
}
```

}